# Playwright for Python: Leaving Tabs and Browser Windows Open After Testing

Tags: python, e2e-testing, playwright-python

Open a new tab manually on a browser open by Playwright

---

I am using Playwright for Python to open a browser, visit a URL and then do some action.

1. Can I keep the browser's window open after my code runs?
2. If I put a breakpoint in my Python code, I can not open a new tab in the browser open by Playwright: the page stays blank. What can I do to keep that tab open?

My code:

```python
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
    
playwright = sync_playwright().start()
browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()
auth_page = context.new_page()
auth_page.goto("https://www.toto.fr/")
print('Put breakpoint here')
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace your breakpoint by `auth_page.pause()`

You can learn more about the api `page.pause()` [here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-pause).